# How to set img class in DOM element echo?

Tags: php, css, react-native, react-redux

How to set img class element echo?

```
<div class="allnis" style="padding: 15px; text-transform: uparcase;">
<?php
            foreach($tv_id->networks as $prod){
               echo "<img value='". $tv_id->name ."' src='".$imgurl_1."".$prod->logo_path."'>" ; 
            }              
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you can set a class the same way you do, for example,

```
<div class="allnis" style="padding: 15px; text-transform: uparcase;">

<?php foreach($tv_id->networks as $prod){ ?>
               <img value="<?php echo $tv_id->name ?>" src="<?php echo $imgurl_1.$prod->logo_path ?> class=" ">
           <?php }   ?>
</div>
```